# Deletion of the content-porter-web8 tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to suggest that we delete the following tag:

https://tridion.stackexchange.com/tags/content-porter-web8/info

I think that this would be covered by tagging questions with both `web8` and `content-porter`.

I couldn't see anywhere on the tag to flag it for review/deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can merge it into content-porter - that's probably the cleanest way to do it?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Do you need to be an admin to do that?